# Spark executor cores not shown in yarn resource manager

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Yarn resource manager is not showing the total cores for the spark application.
For example if we are submiting a spark job with 300 executors and executor-cores is 3. So ideally spark having 900 cores but in yarn resource manager only showing 300 cores.

So is this just a display error or is Yarn not seeing the rest of the 600 cores?

Environment: HDP2.2
Scheduler : capacity-scheduler
Spark : 1.4.1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set

> yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator

in  `capacity-scheduler.xml`

YARN is running more containers than allocated cores because by default [DefaultResourceCalculator](https://apache.googlesource.com/hadoop-common/+/e0c9f893b684246feb5b4adbb95a05a436cdb790/hadoop-yarn-project/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/yarn/util/resource/DefaultResourceCalculator.java) is used. It considers only memory.

```
public int computeAvailableContainers(Resource available, Resource required) {
// Only consider memory
return available.getMemory() / required.getMemory();
  }
```

Use DominantResourceCalculator, It uses both cpu and memory.

you can read more about DominantResourceCalculator [here](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~matei/papers/2011/nsdi_drf.pdf).