# EMR does not detect all the memory

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, amazon-emr

I use EMR 5.18 to run Spark tasks. Here is the setup:

[image]

For any reason, EMR cannot detect all the memory available on the worker nodes. I added nothing to the EMR Configuration part, it's all default settings.

[image]

Any idea what is causing this? Thanks.

Edit: Regarding the value of `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb`. In the UI it says `28672` but in the `yarn-site.xml` it's `352768`

And this is the list of Application installed:
`Hive 2.3.3, Pig 0.17.0, Hue 4.2.0, Spark 2.3.2, Ganglia 3.7.2, Presto 0.210, Livy 0.5.0, Zeppelin 0.8.0, Oozie 5.0.0`

Edit2: it seems the reason is that I have [HBase installed](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hbase-configure.html) but the question now is how to re-allocate memory back.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32233162/spark-executor-cores-not-shown-in-yarn-resource-manager ... let me know if this works

Answer (score 2):

From RM screen, click on every node's HTTP Address link to go to each Node Manager's Web UI.

There, click on Tools > Configuration, and find `yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb` setting. This should indicate how much memory is **allocated to YARN NodeManager** on this node.

EMR sets up the defaults that depend on EC2 instance type and whether HBase is installed or not. They are listed in Amazon's [online documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html):

> You can set configuration variables to tune the performance of your
>   MapReduce jobs... Default values vary based on the EC2 instance type
>   of the node used in the cluster. HBase is available when using Amazon
>   EMR release version 4.6.0 and later. Different defaults are used when
>   HBase is installed.

[Another page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps-running-cluster.html) provides several alternative ways of changing the default values on EMR clusters specifically.

Comment: Ok, I added some info from Amazon guides, but frankly haven't tried it myself.

Answer (score 1):

The memory of spark on EMR is allocated by yarn because the EMR is not only for the yarn applications but it can have a lot of other applications which are not using yarn. So, by default, EMR didn't allow to use whole memory into yarn but it is around 75% of EMR instances. See [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hadoop-task-config.html) and [THIS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-configure-apps.html).

On the second link, one option is supported

```
Application Release label classification    Valid properties    When to use
Spark   spark   maximizeResourceAllocation  Configure executors to utilize the maximum resources of each node.
```

which is what you want. With this option, you can use the [maximized resource allocation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html#emr-spark-maximizeresourceallocation). Set this value when you create the EMR in this way.

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
      "maximizeResourceAllocation": "true"
    }
  }
]
```

The effect is also noted by AWS:

> Sets the maximizeResourceAllocation property to true or false. When true, Amazon EMR automatically configures spark-default properties based on cluster hardware configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand there's a memory overhead but in my case more than half of the memory is not being shown.

Comment: You should attach whole your config, I guess you set the max memory per executors and also might set the number of executors per instance by 1 or something, I can't tell anything yet.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, I set nothing, it's all EMR defaults. I add the default configuration if it helps.

Comment: Have you installed Hbase or other apps? It can cut the allocation memory of yarn as half.

Comment: You can manually config the yarn memory option but it is bad. The reason for cutting memory as a default is to ensure the other apps can run without the lack of memory.   However, you installed Hbase and might use that with spark at the same time and if you modify your memory allocation then Hbase will not work correctly or it can cause errors related to the memory. Anyway, simply you can give the option what you want is the solution. Set the configs `yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb` for the `yarn-site`.